# Batch file for running programs (they don't wait for me)

Tags: vba, batch-file, cmd, wait

My VBA macro has writtin this cmd file

```
cd/d H:\QUB\2dcfd
"C:\ANSYS Inc\v130\icemcfd\win64_amd\bin\icemcfd.bat" -batch -script test0deg.rpl
"C:\ANSYS Inc\v130\fluent\ntbin\win64\fluent.exe" 2d -i test0deg.jou
```

goto directory, execute one program, execute the next program.

If I run it as it is, the first program executes and works fine and the cmd window closes

I'm having problems getting the second on to wait until the first one is finished.

start /wait doesn't work. When I use it it pops a new command window, does the first program (in the new window) then the new command window hangs there. when I manually close this new window it says continue batch file? and i type y and hit return and the second program starts.

Please help. I just want the first one to run and then the second to run after it.

p.s. the second program needs files that the first program makes. That's why I need it in such a way

Thanks in advance

Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Use `call` to call a batch file:

```
call "C:\ANSYS Inc\v130\icemcfd\win64_amd\bin\icemcfd.bat" ...
```

Comment: Yes. It will also make sure that your batch file continues after you call the other batch. That wouldn't be the case with the code you provided in your question where `fluent.exe` would never be called.

Comment: If I use Call it doesnt run the first part and the second part just starts

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using the following:

```
cd/d H:\QUB\2dcfd
cmd /c "C:\ANSYS Inc\v130\icemcfd\win64_amd\bin\icemcfd.bat" -batch -script test0deg.rpl
"C:\ANSYS Inc\v130\fluent\ntbin\win64\fluent.exe" 2d -i test0deg.jou
```

The first one runs, then when it closes, the second one runs.